# Elasticsearch Wildcard fieldtype has slow performance for wildcard queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm testing the new ElasticSearch WildCard field type (https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field) that is supposed to offer better wildcard queries.

Strangely, it seems to be slower for wildcard queries than the default text field.

Is this expected behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

I am searching about approx. 500,000 rows of log data.

With the default text type (though only searches over first 256 chars due to ignore_above):

```
 "result" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }

time curl -X GET "localhost:9200/text-index/_count?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{     "query": {         "wildcard": {             "result": "*dfdskfjdskofsdjf*"      }     } } '
```

= 3.2 Seconds

With the new wildcard field type:

```
"result" : {
          "type" : "wildcard"
        }


time curl -X GET "localhost:9200/wildcard-index/_count?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{     "query": {         "wildcard": {             "result": "*dfdskfjdskofsdjf*"      }     } } '
```

= 24.95 seconds

Comment: do you know if your field data is always less than 256 characters?

Comment: Also how many unique text do you have for this field?

Comment: Mostly unique values but there is repetition of words within them - typical log data.
I've ended up using  a default text field instead of wildcard, with ngram tokenizer. Often longer than 256 characters.

Comment: If data length is more than 256, it means your data is not index in first scenario so it can explain why it was faster. Using Ngram tokenizer might be better option as you did.